# What is returned by np.asarray() called on a sparse matrix as-it-is?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

```
> import scipy
> import numpy as np
> smat_csr = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix([[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]])
> print(smat_csr)

(0, 2)  1
(1, 1)  1

> print(smat_csr.shape)

(3, 3)

> smat_np = np.asarray(smat_csr)
> print(type(smat_np))

<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

So `smat_np` looks like a numpy's array.....

```
> print(smat_np.shape)

()
```

Uhm ... its shape property is an empty tuple!

```
> print(smat_np)

(0, 2)  1
(1, 1)  1
```

Looks like it is still sparse....

Question: What kind of object is the one returned by `np.asarray` when we pass a sparse matrix as-it-is as an argument?

Disclaimer: I know that I can convert the sparse matrix in a dense one using `.todense()`

Comment: It's an array with one element and that element is an object. That object is a sparse matrix.

Comment: @CJR why the shape property is empty?

Comment: Some weird numpy convention? `np.asarray(1).shape` is 0-dimensional also.

Comment: A scalar in NumPy has zero dimensions. The number of dimensions is equivalent to `len(arr.shape)` so that tuple must have zero elements. It's to make the shape/ndim self-consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To numpy a sparse matrix is just a Python object, so it returns a single element, 0d, object dtype array. It doesn't do any sort of conversion. You have to use a sparse method, such as toarray (or .A` for short) to create a numpy array.

That means you have to cautious when passing a sparse matrix to numpy functions. If the function tries to convert it to an array (as it would with a list), it won't work.  If it just delegates the task to object's method(s), it might.

Comment: How does `np.asarray(obj)` decide whether to treat `obj` as a python object instead of doing a conversion? It thought maybe by looking for only tuples. lists and ndarrays. But sometimes other objects (e.g. a `networkx.Graph`) are iterated over instead of slotted in as python objects.

Comment: @dschult, `asarray` describes what it considers to be  `array_like` - as you wrote list or tuple like.  But there is a way for a class to specify how it's to be treated as array. It may be the `__array_function__ protocol`, but I haven't paid much attention to this issue.

Comment: @dschult, I haven't used `networkx`, so can't say anything about the conversion to/from `array` except what I read on pages like https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/convert.html.  There I see there's a `to_numpy_array` function.

Comment: it turns out np.array and friends convert anything that iterates and has a `__len__` operation **and** is not a dict.  A dict seems quite specific, but there we are.  Scipy.sparse arrays do not have a `__len__` operation (except for DOK format which subclasses `dict`) so they are treated as python objects.